# DropDownList Model Binding ASP.NET MVC in a PagedList View

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I need to bind the model with the dropdownlist to create a custom sorting filters. 
My view receives the **"@model PagedList.IPagedList<EmployeeInvestments.Models.Registration>"** as model.

### A part of My View:-

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<EmployeeInvestments.Models.Registration>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AdminDashboard";
}

<div>
    Financial Year:
    <select>
        @foreach(var item in Model)
        {
            <option>@Html.ValueFor(ModelItem=>item.FinancialYear)</option>
        }
    </select>

        Name:
        <select>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <option>@Html.ValueFor(ModelItem => item.Name)</option>
            }
        </select>
        Employee ID:
        <select>
            @foreach(var item in Model)
            {
                <option>@Html.ValueFor(ModelItem=>item.employeeID)</option>
            }
        </select>
</div>
```

I tried the above approach for getting items in dropdownlist but I need unique values in the dropdownlist.

[The image shows what exactly I want to achieve in View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12hjd.png)

I have created a table in the view that lists all users and certain details. So, I need to sort the users based on the filters available in dropdownlist.

> Please refer to image for getting a clear picture of what I need to
> achieve.

Comment: I can help, just need to know if did something in your controller and also can you explain what do you mean by : but I need unique values in the dropdownlist. ?

Comment: I am already passing the list of objects from Controller to View. Secondly, by unique values in dropdownlist, I mean if there are 2 entries with same value, it should just select 1. For e.g if I have 2019,2020,2020 in financial year list then I should get 2019 and 2020 only in Dropdown menu and not 2020,2020,2019.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get Unique date you can use groupby

```
<select>
    @foreach(var item in Model.GroupBy(i=>i.FinancialYear).Select(x => x.Key))
    {
        <option>@Html.ValueFor(ModelItem=>item)</option>
    }
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

To filter by distinct year :

```
Financial Year:
<select>
    @foreach(var item in Model.Select(x => x.FinancialYear).Distinct())
    {
        <option>@Html.ValueFor(ModelItem=>item.FinancialYear)</option>
    }
</select>
```

Comment: Got this error.
Error CS1061 : 'string' does not contain a definition for 'FinancialYear' and no accessible extension method 'FinancialYear' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Let me explain a bit this answer. Model.Select(x => x.FinancialYear) - selects FinancialYear field into string array and after that Distinct() allows you to get unique values. So in this case you iterate over string array and I think you can try to render just "item" variable

Comment: Better you give some of your controller code and model, else cannot help well.